# LoadLibrary() relative address to dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, dll

I am trying to load a dll in my code in windows, I load my dll successfully with LoadLibrary() function but I have a question, I give the path to my dll like:

```
LoadLibrary(C:\\path\\to\\my\\dll);
```

I wonder if I can give the relative path to my dll. I mean for example:

```
LoadLibrary(.\my dll directory\my dll.dll)
```

Is it possible? if not, how can I develop my project which it can be portable without changing the path to dll in different machines?

Comment: yes, it doesn't load :(

Comment: Yes, you can do it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's most likely failing because you forgot to escape the backslashes in your second call to LoadLibrary. Maybe that was a typo when wrote your question, because you also forgot the quote marks for the file name. ;)  That is, change this line:

```
LoadLibrary(.\my dll directory\my dll.dll);
```

To be this:

```
LoadLibrary(L".\\my dll directory\\my dll.dll");
```

(And I'm not sure if the leading `.\\` is needed)

And if that doesn't fix it, then this most likely will do what you need:

```
wchar_t szFullPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, szFullPath);
PathCchAppend(szFullPath, MAX_PATH, L"my dll directory\\my dll.dll");
HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(szFullPath);
```

And finally, LoadLibrary has different behaviors for searching for dependent DLLs.  And it varies based on how you specify the path. That might be what's impacting your ability to load the DLL from a relative search path. [Read the MSDN page on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and consider looking at the various options calls such as [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can do for making search paths easier to deal with. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on DLL search paths as well.

Comment: I encountered another problem, I have made a dll which loads another dll inside. The relative path to first dll successfully loads the first dll, but the relative path inside the first dll does not load the second dll.

Comment: Stop using relative paths. Convert everything to a full path before calling LoadLibrary.  Also, look at the AddDllDirectory() function in addition to SetDllDirectory.

Comment: "Stop using relative paths." Yep. That's the way to do it. You said as much in your answer. As did I in mine.

Comment: Use _relative path_ **or** use _absolute path created dynamically_ but **never** use _direct absolute path_ to a Dll. Note, the "C:" drive not necessarily **equal** to _system drive_!

Comment: If we have `EXE1` which loads `DLL1` which loads `DLL2` with `LoadLibrary`. When I use `LoadLibrary()` on `DLL1`, The relative path is relative ti `DLL1` or `EXE1`?

Comment: I believe it's the EXE.   Easier to just invoke SetDllDirectory and not worry about it.  Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I assume that you meant to write:

```
LoadLibrary(".\\my dll directory\\my dll.dll");
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) answers your question:

> If a relative path is specified, the entire relative path is appended to every token in the DLL search path list. To load a module from a relative path without searching any other path, use GetFullPathName to get a nonrelative path and call LoadLibrary with the nonrelative path.

So yes, you can specify a relative path. But the way it is interpreted is perhaps not what you were expecting. The DLL search will take each path in the DLL search path in turn, combine that with your relative path, and try to load that DLL.

So, if you want your relative path to be relative to the current working directory, call `GetFullPathName` to expand it to an absolute path, and then load that. If you want your relative path to be interpreted relative to some other directory, then combine with that directory and load the DLL with an absolute path.

Comment: Another possibility is to prefix your path with `".;"`.

Comment: @JamesKanze That does something else. Because the rest of the search path will be searched. If you want to load a DLL whose location is given by a relative path, always best to expand the path to absolute and load that.

Comment: I agree.  I didn't say that it was a better possibility.  If you want to load a library from a specific location (and you usually will), then it is definitely better to specify the complete path (perhaps determined dynamically using `GetModuleFileName`.  (Although it _is_ rather odd that Windows uses the path variable when given a name starting with `"./"`.  I suspect that this is a security feature---it does seem a bit dangerous to load based on the current directory.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, relying on current directory is a very bad idea.